# haproxy library not found on internet found log into message

Tags: haproxy

At the time of restart the service we are getting the below error. And library liblua5.3.so is not avail on internet. Please suggest any alternative.

```
/usr/sbin/haproxy-systemd-wrapper: error while loading shared libraries: liblua-5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Perhaps don't use a binary linked against a library you can't find?

Answer (score 0):

no easy answers here,  you have a dependency issue. IF your lucky the easy solution is it reinstall haproxy, using your linux distro's package management system (apt, yum  etc)

your friendly package manager should install the  lastest version of haproxy and install  all the libraries  haproxy depends on.

But  as your in the situation already it indicates that perhaps you compiled haproxy yourself or  package management on your OS is already a bit broke. so  you might hit issues solves things the easy way.

Answer (score 0):

yum install lua lua-devel if you're running a RedHat-OS or apt-get install lua lua-dev for Ubuntu/Debian although I don't have a Debian/Ubuntu box at hand to test if this is the actual package name :)